# Lxml - Difference between errog_log with XML Tools

Tags: python, xml, lxml, error-log

My teams and I are often using XML Tool with Notepad to open the xml file and validate it with an XSD file. We have hundreds of xml file so to make it faster, I wrote a python script using lxml.

However, for the same xml and xsd files, I don't have the same result in the errog_log between Lxml and XML Tools

When I validate with XML Tools , I get a pop-up, printing this :

```
ERROR: Element '{http://www.cnav.fr/n4ds}S10_G00_00_005': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '3' is not an element of the set {'02'}.
ERROR: Element '{http://www.cnav.fr/n4ds}S10_G00_00_005': '3' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
ERROR: Element '{http://www.cnav.fr/n4ds}S20_G00_05_005': '2020-AA-01' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
```

And when I'm using lxml, I have this on my console :

```
ERROR: Element '{http://www.cnav.fr/n4ds}S10_G00_00_005': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '3' is not an element of the set {'02'}.
ERROR: Element '{http://www.cnav.fr/n4ds}S20_G00_05_005': '2020-AA-01' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.
```

I would like to know from where difference in logs come from.

PS : I have lxml 4.7.1.0, which is using libxml 2.9.10 and libxslt 1.1.34,
and XML Tools 2.4.9.2 Unicode 64 bit on Notepad, which is using libxml 2.9.3 and libxslt 1.1.28

Best regards.

Comment: Notepad++ (not Notepad) has an XML Tools plugin. XML Tools 2.4.9.2 is rather old (from Oct 2016). lxml 4.7.1.0 on the other hand is quite recent (from Dec 2021).

Comment: I actually manage the same log_error than XML Tools plugins by downgrading my lxml 4.7.1 to 4.6.5. Thanks a lot